# Circular Reference between 2 classes

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a problem trying to solve this circular reference.

First I have two `NSManagedObject` `ACoreData` and `BCoreData`
I want to separate the model from the DataBase layer to the UI Model.

So, I create `A` and `B` classes which those will be in the UI.

I have created a protocol (`Convertible`) that `ACoreData` and `BCoreData` will implement to convert to the ui objects.

So far so good, but now I have a problem. Each time I call convert from `ACoreData` it will create a new `A` and it will assign the `BCoreData` converted, but then the `BCoreData` object will call convert again for the `A` object. I will end up with a loop calling `convert()` each other.

This is the code:

```
protocol Convertible{
    associatedtype T
    func convert() -> T
}

class ACoreData: Convertible{
    var b: BCoreData?
    func convert() -> A {
        var a = A()
        a.b = self.b?.convert()
        return a
    }
}


class BCoreData: Convertible{
    var a: ACoreData?

    func convert() -> B {
        var b = B()
        b.a = self.a?.convert()
        return b
    }
}

class A{
    var b: B?
}

class B{
    var a: A?
}
```

Do you know how can I solve this problem to avoid the loop in this circle reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going out of your way to make things difficult. Why have two classes to represent the same model object?

Comment: Because I dont want the NSmanagedObjects in the UI @TomHarrington this is one of the principles of clean architecture

Comment: @TomHarrington maybe you are right, I can have all of the attributes together in one class

Comment: Worst case, if @TomHarrington's suggestion doesn't work out, you can use flags, didSet, and defer to break the circular chain.

Comment: @Feldur Thanks, but if you take a look at the code, each time you call convert it will create a new B or A, so the internal a or b attribute will be always nil and it will begins the circular chain.

Comment: Make the flags static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that the best solution is **don't do this**. You're adding a lot of complexity to your code for no real advantage. Weigh the benefits you see for keeping managed objects away from the UI against the additional complexity of needing to convert to/from managed objects all the time, copying values from one to the other any time one of them changes, the memory hit of keeping duplicate copies of data around, and probably other stuff I haven't thought of yet. "Clean" architecture is going to cost you a lot in terms of maintainability and performance.

If you don't want the UI to know about managed objects, define a protocol that your managed objects adopt. Make the UI work with "things that implement the protocol" instead of managed objects. Keeping the UI unaware of the details of the data store does not require duplicate data models.